# Change Bootstrap header link color on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a new *Bootstrap* project that changes the background color, header text color and **navigation link color** as a user scrolls down the page with a parallax image.

I've managed to change the color of the header background and the title text with some borrowed jQuery here at Stack, but the problem is the `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` being applied to the `ul.navbar.nav > li > a` link. I've tried to write the link this way `ul.navbar.nav.li.a` and without the `ul`, but to no joy.

I've tried other ways of referencing link through the `<div>` and then with the `id` all to no avail. Everything that shows up with *Google's Inspect* feature has been tried, but no go.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('.navbar-fixed-top').addClass('opaque');
    $('.h2-style').addClass('opaque');
    $('ul.navbar-nav>li>a').addClass('custom');
  } else {
    $('.navbar-fixed-top').removeClass('opaque');
    $('.h2-style').removeClass('opaque');
    $('ul.navbar-nav>li>a').removeClass('custom');
  }
});
```

```css
.navbar-fixed-top {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  transition: background-color 2s ease 0s;
}

.navbar-fixed-top.opaque {
  background-color: rgba(41, 128, 185, 0.95);
  transition: background-color 2s ease 0s;
}

ul.navbar-nav.custom>li>a {
  color: #FFF !important;
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #FF9800;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><h2 class="h2-style">3 Strikes <span class="h3-style">Stops Repeat Offenders</span></h2></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Studies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Mike's Desk</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">3S Law <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#contact">3S Law</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">3S Crimes</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">More <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Friends of 3S</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Book Page</a></li>        
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Begin page content. The travel for 500px is there to accommodate a large graphic (parallax--bg) for a proportional parallax scroll feature. It is critical for the effect.// -->

<section class="bgimg">
  <div class="parallax--bg feature-text">        
    <h1 class="h1-style">Three Strikes and <br>You're Out!</h1>        
  </div> <!--  .parallax--bg //-->
</section> <!--  .bgimg //-->
```

I'm using Bootstrap's fixed footer template.

Anyone have any ideas?

TIA

Comment: Can you post the HTML you are targeting?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Naltroc, do you wish to see the page itself? Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

You have the selectors mixed up between your CSS and your JS.

In CSS you use: `ul.navbar-nav.custom>li>a`
Your JS creates: `ul.navbar-nav>li>a.custom`       (`$('ul.navbar-nav>li>a').addClass('custom');`)

You could change either your CSS or JS...
But in fact you can remove most of your JS and base all the changes in your CSS on the added `opaque` class for the `navbar-fixed-top`.
*You can remove the `!important` from your CSS, you should never want to use those anyway.*

See **code snippet** for a demo:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 30) {
    $('.navbar-fixed-top').addClass('opaque');
  } else {
    $('.navbar-fixed-top').removeClass('opaque');
  }
});
```

```css
.navbar-fixed-top {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 1);
  transition: background-color 2s ease 0s;
}
.navbar-fixed-top.opaque {background-color:rgba(41,128,185, 0.95);}

.navbar-fixed-top .h2-style {
  transition: color 2s ease 0s;
}
.navbar-fixed-top.opaque .h2-style {color:#AA0;}

.navbar-fixed-top ul.navbar-nav li>a {
  transition: color 2s ease 0s;
}
.navbar-fixed-top.opaque ul.navbar-nav li>a {color:#FFF;}
.navbar-fixed-top.opaque ul.navbar-nav li>a:hover {color:#FF9800;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><h2 class="h2-style">3 Strikes <span class="h3-style">Stops Repeat Offenders</span></h2></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Studies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Mike's Desk</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">3S Law <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#contact">3S Law</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">3S Crimes</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">More <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Friends of 3S</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Book Page</a></li>        
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Begin page content -->
<section class="bgimg">
  <div class="parallax--bg feature-text">        
    <h1 class="h1-style">Three Strikes and <br>You're Out!</h1>        
  </div> <!--  .parallax--bg //-->
</section> <!--  .bgimg //-->
```

- I changed `ul.navbar-nav>li>a` to `ul.navbar-nav li>a` so that the nested links also turn white. I assume that's what you want, but if it's not you know where it's coming from.
- I added CSS for `.navbar-fixed-top .h2-style` and `.navbar-fixed-top.opaque .h2-style`, just so you can see that change in action too.
- I removed the `transition: background-color 2s ease 0s;` from `.navbar-fixed-top.opaque`. You don't need it because the base selector already has it.
- I added a `transition: color 2s ease 0s;` to `.navbar-fixed-top ul.navbar-nav li>a`. Thought you might like that:)

Comment: @tecombs am I missing something, not the answer you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks Funky, your corrections worked a treat. Now all works as intended, I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @tecombs Well you would make my day by officially accepting my answer, by clicking on the checkmark underneath the score counter -
 at the top-left of my answer:). Not only will you reward me for my work, other people will know that this problem has a solution. And if you're really really happy, you could even give me an extra scorepoint too by also clicking on the up-arrow above the score, but that's just icing on the cake

Comment: I apologize, I wasn't familiar with proper etiquette. But I have a remaining difficulty, the background color and the link color are the same and therefore lack distinction. Again, I've tried but was unsuccessful. That's what brought me here. Are you using Codepen?

Comment: @tecombs no problem, you don't know until someone tells you, right:) [Check out the official tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and you'll know exactly how the site works (only takes a few minutes).

Comment: @tecombs I'm not exactly sure what you mean by the same color though. I've worked with CodePen yes, you want to drop a link where I can see the problem? And am I understanding correct that this is a new problem that is not visible in the code snippet in my answer?

Comment: I gave 2 points but since I've less than 6 they don't record it until reviewed.

Comment: The problem remaining is that text/link color is white and the .active background color is #e7e7e7 I believe according to Chrome's Inspector. To me this CSS is advanced beyond any classes I've had so far and all I know to use is the Inspect tool. I even installed Firefox to see if that helped, but no, it did not. You can view the site at http://www.ccpcv.org/home.html. I hope you don't freak, it is a conservative law and order page. Once the Bootstrap template is finished, I'll add Wordpress/PHP to bring it to life.

Comment: @tecombs Now I see what you mean! That's easy. In the code snippet in my answer, this is the second to last line of CSS: `.navbar-fixed-top.opaque ul.navbar-nav li>a {color:#FFF;}`. And like you said in your comment, the problem is the menu button with class *.active*. You may also have noticed that it's the *li* that has the *.active* class. So, just copy that CSS line and paste it right after the last line (with *:hover*), like so: `.navbar-fixed-top.opaque ul.navbar-nav li.active>a {color:#555;}`. (I just added class *.active* to the *li* in the selector.)

Comment: @tecombs And if you want the text or the button to get yet another color when the active button is hovered, then just copy the line with *:hover*, paste it right after the last line, and add the *.active* class again: `.navbar-fixed-top.opaque ul.navbar-nav li.active>a:hover {background-color:#97C7E7;}`. (I changed the *background-color* this time instead of the text *color*, it's completely up to you what you want, you could also change both.)

Comment: Thank very much Funky, I'll get to work on this and then it's on to the rest of the project. You're help is worth 10 points or more, I'll click the button again to see what happens. Is there some software you use to track the effects of changes. I need all the "extra" I can get. And sadly it seems my points won't count at all due to my being only a 6. Sigh.

Comment: @tecombs :D if you click the upvote again you won't upvote it twice, you will actually undo your first upvote. But that's fine, leave it, if you're happy with my answer you can accept it, there shouldn't be a restriction on that. [**See this image**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to see what I mean by "accepting an answer".